# Transition effect does not transition image it removes it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently making my first website with Html, and javascript as the front end will come first.

I am trying to create a Collapse Sidebar which appears when I click the button on the right hand side of the top-nav but I have a problem with the transition effect as it will push the everything to the right hand side but in doing so the image does not show up and the top nav is not covering the top but rather a bit below the top of the page how can this be fixed?

I have taken away the `<div id="main">` and in doing so the background-image reappears and the top nav is covering the top of the page where a top nav should be however the sidebar now covers apart of the page instead of moving it to the right.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bgimg_1 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1.0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.sidebar{
 backfround-color: red;
   }
   .bgimg_1{
 background-image: 
 href("https://cdn.athemes.com/wp-content/uploads/Original-JPG-Image.jpg");
 min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="Reids Hub">Reids Hub</a>
    <button class="openbtn" class="tips" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
  </div>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">What started all of this.</a>
    <a href="#">About me.</a>
    <a href="#">Projects.</a>
    <a href="#">Contacts.</a>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg_1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">SCROLL DOWN</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I expected for the everything to go right and it does but I also expected for the image to transition the rest of the page in fact the image disappears.

Comment: @FZs I don't see how that is an Error

Comment: Can you post the whole code or create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanveer Shah i will do that.

Comment: You forgot the JavaScript and please provide the code as a [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne The JavaScript is now in the post.

Comment: @FZs  quickly remove your comment

Answer (score 0):

## Invalid Syntax

`background-image` correct syntax is:

> `background-image:` **url**`(http://host.top/path/to/img.jpg);`

---

#### Layout

Also, if you want a background that covers the entire viewport (fancy word for screen), put it in a parent element commonly it's `body`, If that was your intention then remove `.Bg_img1`. The whole thing. Add the following styles to `body` (see **Demo 1**):

> ```
> body {
>   font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
>   background-image: url(https://3jbq2ynuxa-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/pasted-image-0-19.png);
>   background-attachment: fixed;
>   background-position: center;
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;
>   background-size: cover;
> }
> ```

If you prefer to keep the `background-image` on the right side, then instead of the `body` add this to `#main`(see **Demo 2**):

> ```
> #main { 
>   background-image: url(https://3jbq2ynuxa-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/pasted-image-0-19.png);
>   background-position: center;
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;
>   background-size: cover;
>   transition: margin-left .5s;
>   padding: 16px;
>   color: #fff;
>   min-height: 100vh;
> }
> ```

---

### Demo 1

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  background-image: url(https://3jbq2ynuxa-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/pasted-image-0-19.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

### Demo 2

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
   font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main { 
  background-image: url(https://3jbq2ynuxa-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/pasted-image-0-19.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time I have changed some of the code but I don't know if I explained everything correctly. How would you get that background image to be pushed to the right as the contents of
<h2> <p> have been and still have it fill the page?

Comment: @Orion gotcha, see **Demo 2**

Comment: Np problem, sir. FYI, when you post the next time around make sure to use the code editor, I did it for you today to save us time. Just click the icon with the angle brackets: `<>`. To accept this answer click the checkmark located at the top left corner of this post.✅